# Best way to implement a three state toggle in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, zustand

I am creating some buttons in react that trigger a state change from one to the next. Some of my buttons have three states, represented by an enum. The three states should be set in consecutive order. When the last value is reached, the next action should set the state back to the first value of the enum again. What is a neat way of implementing this?

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { devtools, persist, createJSONStorage } from 'zustand/middleware'
import { BackgroundVariant as Background } from 'reactflow';

function nextBackground(background: Background): Background {
  switch (background) {
    case Background.Dots:
      return Background.Cross;
    case Background.Cross:
      return Background.Lines;
    default:
      return Background.Dots;
  };
};

interface MenuState {
  background: Background;
  toggleBackground: () => void;
}

export const useMenuStore = create<MenuState>()(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (set) => ({
        background: Background.Dots,
        toggleBackground: () => set((state) => ({
          background: nextBackground(state.background)
        }))
      }),
      {
        name: 'menu-storage',
        storage: createJSONStorage(() => localStorage),
      }
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, what is the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: Function has to be changed when the enum changes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of a function that takes any enum and will return the next value or the first value if it is the last:

```
function getNextEnumValue<T extends Record<string, string>>(enumObj: T, currentValue: T[keyof T]): T[keyof T] {
  const enumValues = Object.values(enumObj);
  const enumKeys = Object.keys(enumObj) as (keyof T)[];
  const currentIndex = enumKeys.findIndex(key => enumObj[key] === currentValue);

  if (currentIndex === -1) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid enum value: ${currentValue}`);
  }

  const nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  if (nextIndex === enumKeys.length) {
    return enumObj[enumKeys[0]];
  }

  const nextValue = enumObj[enumKeys[nextIndex]];
  if (!enumValues.includes(nextValue)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid enum value: ${nextValue}`);
  }

  return nextValue;
}
```